# ansible command to list all known hosts

Tags: ansible

Ansible is already installed in a seperated ec2 instance.
I need to install apache on an ec2 instance.

Trying to find a list of known hosts

I run this command 
ansible -i hosts all --list-hosts

and get this message
 [WARNING]: Host file not found: hosts

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available

[WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do

Comment: The warning here is likely the problem. You've provided the `-i hosts` flag to indicate to Ansible that your inventory file is named "hosts" and that file does not exist; therefore, Ansible has no inventory for which to list the hosts

Answer (score 3):

`--list-hosts` lists hosts that match a `--limit`. The input is the `-i`, [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html). Your inventory is a file named `hosts`, which doesn't exist.

You need to create or generate an inventory file from *somewhere*. Ansible can't intuit what your inventory is.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ansible by Pip, you need to create a directory with ansible.cfg and hosts file. For it, use:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/ansible/
sudo touch /etc/ansible/hosts
```

So you will be able to use the command below:

```
cat /etc/ansible/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

Got permission to ssh to the target server. Now i can install on this target server.
If I can login as an ec2-user by being part of a management domain then I can access any server